# tar two directories with the same name to one archived directory

Tags: linux, bash, unix, debian

What I'm doing is:
tar -czf etc.tar.gz /etc /usr/local/etc

And when I extract it I will have two directories:
1) etc
2) usr

What I want is to do it this way that I will have only etc after extracting with contents of this two directories.

Thanks.

Is there any other way than creating temporary directory with merged files from /etc and /usr/local/etc and then removing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cd /
tar -cf /path/to/etc.tar etc/
cd /usr/local
tar -rf /path/to/etc.tar etc/
cd /path/to
gzip etc.tar
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think that tar -rcf /path/to/etc.tar etc/ should look like tar -rf /path/to/etc.tar etc/
cause we don't want to create again a new archive? Am I right?

Comment: Good catch; thanks.  Editing the answer to reflect this.